# Chef ruby block until file created

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Im a newbie in ruby, question is how to do ruby_block in chef that checks until a file is created.?

I started my code with my other ruby block,like..

```
ruby_block "block_until_not_operational" do
  block do
    10.times do
      if IO.popen("netstat -lnt").entries.select { |entry|
          entry.split[3] =~ /:#{node[:jboss][:default_port]}$/
        }.size == 0
        break
      end
      Chef::Log.debug("service[jenkins] still listening (port #{node[:jboss][:default_port]})")
      sleep 1
    end
  end
  action :nothing
end
```

Comment: so what's the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use the Jenkins cookbook as an example:

- https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins/blob/ffbde317016bdbadfee7f8da66372ab946a31fdf/recipes/server.rb#L100

If has a "block_until_operational" ruby block which is triggered by notify actions in other resources, for example:

```
  notifies :start, 'service[jenkins]', :immediately
  notifies :create, 'ruby_block[block_until_operational]', :immediately
```